# Gallifrey and Krikket, a connection?

Tags: doctor-who, the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy, douglas-adams

Is the time bubble around Gallifrey meant to resemble the envelope of Slo-Time around Krikket? I know Douglas Adams made [Slartibartfast](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/22437/3804) after the Doctor, and although the episodes with the time bubble are after Douglas' time, is this a nod towards him?

The Gallifreyans could have been written off as dead or lost or...anything really in the new series. But they are trapped in a time-bubble much like the Krikkets.

Coincidence?

Comment: The HHGG planet is called "Krikkit."  "Wikkit" is only used when describing the Wikkit Gate that kept it locked away.

Comment: Thanks @Jwodder but in the future feel free to make such edits yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously there are no cite-able sources for this, But given Douglas Adams' penchant for poking fun at as many things as he would within the pages, your hypothesis makes sense for Krikkit being an analogue for Gallifrey.

Also, given Russel T. Davies' longstanding involvement in the Sci-Fi community the irony of nodding back to Adams' work in such a way seems rather.... fitting.

Comment: It's the other way round, the time bubble around Gallifrey came long after Krikkit

Answer (score 3):

As Gallifrey isn't actually trapped in a bubble of slow time I don't think there's a connection like you suggest. The war is in a "time lock" and Galifrey is in a pocket universe.

However, there are connections between Galifrey and Krikket. As detailed in 
[Did the Doctor inspire Slartibartfast?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/22465/13024), Adams wrote *Doctor Who and the Krikketmen*, which ended up being adapted into Doctor Who's sixteenth season (*The Key to Time*) and of course *Life the Universe and Everything*. Krikket was never equated with Galifrey. Instead I believe it was the Time Lords who imprisoned Krikket.

Adams was also the script editor for season seventeen, and wrote *Shada* which was adapted into *Dirk Gentley's Holistic Detective Agency*.